# error explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given

Tags: php

The following code returns this error.

> explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(no_trans) as nomor FROM tb_periksa");
    $trans_prefix = "08201";
    $x = explode($trans_prefix, $sql);
    $no_trans = $trans_prefix.str_pad(($x[1]+1), 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>
Nomor Transaksi: 
<input type="text" name="no_trans" id="no_trans" value=<?php echo sprintf($no_trans);?>>
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error? It seems pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve there?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to explode the returned resource. You need to fetch it first. If it were more than one row you would need to while loop the fetch.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM); $row[0];
echo $row[0];
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data.

Here's the manual on fetch_array, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php. Also note that the `mysql_` functions are now deprecated. `PDO` or `mysqli` functions should now be used for DB interactions.

Full (untested) example:

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(no_trans) as nomor FROM tb_periksa");
    $trans_prefix = "08201";
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_NUM); $row[0];
    $x = explode($trans_prefix, $row[0]);
    $no_trans = $trans_prefix.str_pad(($x[1]+1), 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>
Nomor Transaksi: 
<input type="text" name="no_trans" id="no_trans" value=<?php echo sprintf($no_trans);?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`explode()` splits a string using the delimiter provided in the first parameter.

The error message is correct. You are passing a the result of `mysql_query` as the second parameter to `explode` via your `$sql` variable. `mysql_query` returns resource type, hence your variable `$sql` is of type resource and not string.

Please see the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/explode) for the `explode()` function.

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will no longer be supported in future releases. Please use `mysqli_*` functions or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the MySQL query result into a mysql_fetch* command to get actual results back.  You are currently passing the reference to the database result set into explode rather than the result set itself.